# How to plot a table of summary in LaTeX

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I'm having a hard time to plot the table as shown below.

[image: Table of Summary]

Could anyone please share with me the similar corresponding code/template or any easy fix for this?

Comment: What did you try so far and what exactly is the problematic part?

Comment: For the shorter ghorizpnal lines that span only some columns, you could use \cline, for example as in \cline{3-6}.

Comment: How long are the actual contents of your table cells? Are they just a few words just like in your dummy example or will there also be longer texts that span multiple lines?

Comment: Give me a minute, I will include the code. The length of texts vary, some of them can be a lot longer than my dummy example. @leandriis

Comment: Why `\multicolumn`? I can't see a cell spanning to columns in the image you included, apart from the "Methods"  cell in the column headers. Also, the image shows a total of 6 columns, your code only contains 5 of them and the column headers do not match. Please clarify.

Comment: I thought it should be `\multicolumn` for Sample and Ignore Me under Methods

Comment: To make sure, the columm header "Methods" spans two columns, you can use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{textbf{Methods}}`.

Comment: Since you mentioned, some cells will contain longer texts, please clarify which of them. Are they all in one column or in different columns? How long will the text be? How should your table behave regarding linebreaks inside of these cells?

Comment: Everything under Type column and the Sample under Methods column will be as short as the text in my dummy example. Anything under Reference column will be a citation. Things under Tools column range from 6 to 50 characters. Things under Outcome column range from 50 to 150 characters.

Comment: The Ignore Me under Methods column range from 30 to 50 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two different approaches, both based on `tabularx` in order to make sure the table does not exceed the available textwidth, while at the same time allowing linebreaks in the columns with longer texts.

In the first example, I also used `\makegapedcells` from the `makecell` package to add a bit of white space above and below the contents of each cell to prevent the text from toughing the horizontal lines. In the second example, I used a different approach based on `booktabs`, no vertical lines and just a few horizontal lines.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\makegapedcells
    \caption{Table of Summary}
    \label{tos}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|p{2cm}|c|p{2cm}|X|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Methods}} & \textbf{References} & \textbf{Tools} & \textbf{Outcome}\\
    \hline
    \hline
        Ignore Me & Sample & a little bit longer text in this cell & Ignore Me & a little bit longer text in this cell & This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{2-6}
                  & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \hline
    \hline
        Ignore Me & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Table of Summary}
    \label{tos}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llp{2cm}lp{2cm}X}
    \toprule
        Type & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Methods} & References & Tools & Outcome\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
        Ignore Me & Sample & a little bit longer text in this cell & Ignore Me & a little bit longer text in this cell & This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \midrule
        Ignore Me & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

`xltabular` version to allow the table to occupy multiple pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}


{\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|c|c|p{2cm}|c|p{2cm}|X|}
    \caption{Table of Summary}
\label{tos}\\
\hline
    \textbf{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Methods}} & \textbf{References} & \textbf{Tools} & \textbf{Outcome}\\
\hline
\hline \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{Table of Summary - continued from previous page}\\ % comment out this line if you don't want a repeated caption on the second and following pages.
\hline
    \textbf{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Methods}} & \textbf{References} & \textbf{Tools} & \textbf{Outcome}\\
\hline
\hline \endhead
        Ignore Me & Sample & a little bit longer text in this cell & Ignore Me & a little bit longer text in this cell & This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{2-6}
                  & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \hline
    \hline
        Ignore Me & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \cline{3-6}
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \hline
    \end{xltabular}}





    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{llp{2cm}lp{2cm}X}
        \caption{Table of Summary}
    \label{tos}\\
    \toprule
        Type & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Methods} & References & Tools & Outcome\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
    \endhead
        Ignore Me & Sample & a little bit longer text in this cell & Ignore Me & a little bit longer text in this cell & This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. This cell contains a longer text. \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \midrule
        Ignore Me & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\ \addlinespace
                  &        & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much

Comment: The solution is working perfectly fine. I've one last question. How to make this table that you created span multiple pages? I tried to use `\begin{longtable}` but it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: I edited my answer to also include the `xltabular` versions of the table. This package combines the features of `longtable` (mid-table page breaks)  with `tabularx` (flexible width `X` columns) and is therefore the package I would use for this particular table.

Comment: Amazing! It's working fine but as the table spans multiple pages, the same caption appears multiple times. Multiple _Table of Summary_ appear in the _List of Tables_. Is there any solution/hack for this?

Comment: I get that you want a single entry in the list of tables, but you you also still want the caption to repeat on the second and following pages, like it currently does? I have updated my answer to include a suggestion for both cases:With and without repeated caption on the second and following pages, while at the same time just having a single entry in the list of tables.

Comment: Yes, I only want a single entry in the list of tables. I only want the caption to appear once at the beginning of the table. I do not want it to repeat on the second and following pages.

Comment: Cool! Perfect score. Thank you so muchhhhh

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{l|}}
\hline
Type &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ Methods} &   Reference & Tools & Outcome\\
\hline
\hline
Ignore Me & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & \\\cline{3-6}
 &  & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & \\\cline{3-6}
 &  & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & \\\cline{3-6}
 & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & \\\cline{2-6}
 &  & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & \\
\hline
\hline
Ignore Me & Sample & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & Ignore Me & \\\cline{3-6}
 &  &  &  &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: tabular]